# Can I get the lambda calculus for free from Cartesian closed categories?

Tags: category-theory

I have heard the simply typed lambda calculus is the internal language of closed Cartesian categories.

I have a written a compiler from the STLC to CCCs but this involves a lot of ugly tuple shuffling.

Is it possible to get the STLC for free from the definition of a closed Cartesian category?

Comment: Have you seen [Compiling to Categories](http://conal.net/papers/compiling-to-categories/)?

Comment: @jmite yeah. I have even written such compilers myself as I mentioned in the question. But one can compile to assembly code as well. I feel like lambda calculus is supposed to have a deeper relationship to cccs than to assembly code.